# Can a default Duuk-Tsarith perform the Stone-To-Flesh spell for creation of a Watcher?

Tags: darksword-adventures

I have started putting together a Darksword campaign for friends, and come to what is either just a universe consistency issue (which I can deal with) or a misunderstanding of the rules on my part (which would be bad).

As per the books, the ritual of turning a human into a Watcher (a 30 ft immortal, sentient, stone statue and a form of punishment) is performed by a Duuk-Tsarith (which is essentially a character class).

My understanding of the 'Living Change' spell effect (as per the RPG) is that it requires the 'healing' ability (that is, a score of 1 or more), one of the few abilities unavailable to the Duuk-Tsarith. I know that this ritual will be a key plot point in the campaign and want it to especially be a defining moment for a PC playing a Duuk-Tsarith. I was especially confused because in the section that describes Living Change effects, the example they use cites a Duuk-Tsarith character declaring that they will perform a living change spell to change x and y attributes, though frustratingly when they come to the next example (where the ability scores are actually pertinent), they use a different character and the healing ability score to resolve the effect.

If it turns out that this ability was just withheld from Duuk-Tsarith in the RPG because they are already mechanically OP without it then that's totally something I understand, and I will just discuss with the player scaling one of their other stats to allow for some innate ability in healing. I am really more just worried that this displays a key misunderstanding on my part of the way magical effects work, and if so I wish to correct it.

The third possibility which now comes to mind is that maybe the part I am misunderstanding is the character creation process - My reading of the process was the use the character class stats which are presented in the 'Mystery of x' chapters (where x is Fire, Water, Wind, Earth, Life, etc...), but is it possibly referring to a different table when it says to "copy in the attributes and ability scores for your class"? (My thinking here is that the tables I have been using may have been for the average NPC Duuk-Tsarith, rather than the PC class). If there is a 'PC Duuk-Tsarith' class, maybe it includes the healing ability?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions you can try.  The first: DKarn-duuk and Duuk-tsarith are both born to the Mystery of Fire, though only DKarn-duuk have any Water talent as per the DA book.  It wouldn't be too much of a stretch to say some (rare) Duuk-tsarith also possess/learned the same talent, perhaps trained specifically for that purpose at the Mountain: creating Watchers.   These few Duuk-tasrith can't do any other druid or shaman work, just a select few can create Watchers.  This also keeps these particular black robes balanced.

The second: have the Duuk-tasrith harness his Catalyst's own innate Water ability to turn flesh into stone.  The Catalyst could never even attempt this himself, but with the Duuk-tasrith's power and training, the black robe can perform the spell through the Catalyst by utilizing the latter's Water ability (which the Catalyst can't even tap into -- poor guy).  Again, for balance, you can disallow this combo to parallel into any healing or other Water magic.

These two solutions can also work together.  The Duuk-tasrith (some or all) are trained at the Mountain to utilize their Catalyst, which is necessary anyway for the spell, specifically for the ritual of creating a Watcher.

It's great to see people still playing this -- I thought it was long gone.  I only found this thread by Googling randomly.